# Открытый урок по испанскому языку

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, предлоги

Можно ли так сказать: *открытый урок **по** испанскому языку*?

Answer (score 1):

**УРОК**
[**Толковый словарь Ожегова**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/253050):
1. Учебный час (в средних учебных заведениях), посвященный отдельному предмету. Учитель даёт урок. Урок математики. Урок музыки. Звонок на урок, с урока.

[**Викисловарь**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA):
1. Учебный час, занятие **по** определённому предмету.
Сегодня было четыре урока. *Следующий урок — **по** русскому языку.*

[**Толковый словарь Ушакова**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1101206):
3. *без доп., **чего*** или (*разг*.) ***по чему*** (*в чем* или *из чего устар*.).
 Учебный час (или иной период времени), посвященный отдельному предмету (в школе или в домашнем обучении).

***Открытый урок*** (чего?) **испанского языка**.
**Открытый урок** (по чему?) **по испанскому языку.**

Получается, что можно сказать и без предлога, и с предлогом, но форма *открытый урок испанского языка* более грамотна, предпочтительна.

Есть предложения, в которых (на мой взгляд) лучше употреблять ***по***.
Например:
*Сегодня в сотнях школ Вологодчины прошли открытые уроки по Основам безопасности жизнедеятельности.

1 сентября в ростовских школах прошли открытые уроки по профориентации.

...ко дню энергетика во всех школах г. Сочи прошли открытые уроки по энергосбережению*.

Answer (score 0):

Так сказать можно ввиду очевидного контекста: урок здесь имеет смысл **занятия** (для всех желающих), проводимого **по** названному **предмету**. Однако было бы неудачным выражение: "*он преподал мне урок по испанскому языку*" (здесь нужно "испанского языка", особенно, если это говорится в переносном смысле - о поучительном случае и т. п.) - здесь акцент на доносимом до адресата **содержании**, а не на форме *мероприятия*.